# How to grep without hidden files?

Tags: command-line, grep

I have two different regular files:  myscript2 and myscript3 with word 'dash' inside. I want to grep them, but because of '-r' addition to grep I got hidden files as well. I tried to use 'grep -v' after pipe to get rid of hidden files. I failed. Why? What to do to solve my problem?

```
$ ls
myscript2
myscript3
$ cat myscript2
dash
$ grep -r -l 'dash' | grep -v '^.*'
```

Comment: My question is not about specified file name, but all possible files.

Comment: All of those answers can adapted to cover that case as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try `--exclude`:

```
grep -R --exclude='.*' <pattern> <dir>
```

Comment: thomasrutter, II have tried. It shows hidden files again.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk works fine for me. What version of `grep` and Ubuntu are you using? What was the exact command you tried?

Comment: excluding `.*` seems to exclude all results if calling grep from same directory `.`